# Training Data for Spacy from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and I am currently strugglint with converting a dataframe into a the followinf format.

As an example, I have the following dataframe (df1):

```
   fulltext                                   text       start    end     text1     start1  end1
0   Android Pay expands to Canada             Canada      23      29      0         0       0
1   Google Maps launches location sharing     Google       0      6       location  21      29
```

the output I am trying to reach from this dataframe:

```
[
    ("Android Pay expands to Canada", {"entities": [(23, 29, "entity")]}),
    ("Google Maps launches location sharing", {"entities": [(0, 6, "entity"), (21, 29, "entity")]}),
]
```

I have tried:
1)

```
List =  []
for index, rows in df1.iterrows():
    my_list = [rows.start, rows.end]
    List.append(my_list)
    my_list.append('entity')
print(List)
```

and got the following output:

```
[[23, 29, 'entity'], [0, 6, 'entity']]
```

2)
converting into tuple:

```
List_tuple = [tuple(l) for l in List]
```

output:

```
[(23, 29, 'entity'), (0, 6, 'entity')]
```

But this is only the columns "start" and "end" ((21, 29, "entity") is missing because it is start1 and end 1). Could you please advice how I could proceed to make this sort of list for n amount of rows (I have a large number of rows), and in case there are values in column "start1", "end1", "start2", "end2" etc. - put them together in the list(which is inside of a dictionary) as shown here?

```
[
    ("Android Pay expands to Canada", {"entities": [(23, 29, "entity")]}),
    ("Google Maps launches location sharing", {"entities": [(0, 6, "entity"), (21, 29, "entity")]}),
]
```

Thanks so much in advance for any recommendations! I have been struggling with it and I am stuck without knowing how to proceed...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
df['fulltext'].apply(lambda x: (x,{'entities':[(0,len(x),'entity')]})).tolist()
```

This is a partial solution.
You can expand same to your entities

Answer (score 0):

```
df.apply(lambda x: (x['fulltext'],{'entities':[(x['start'],x['end'],'entity')]}),axis=1).tolist()
```

Hopefully this would solve your problem.